# Vector space generation after union of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Page 18 of Springer texts of matrix algebra states, under the heading *Unions & direct sums of vector spaces*:

> The vector space generated by the union of the sets in the individual vector spaces is easy to form since $(V,o)$ and $(W,o)$ are vector spaces, so for any vector $x$ in either $V$ or $W$, $ax$ is in that set.

How is this possible? Let us say $V=[2,4,7,5]$ and $W=[5,8,2,1]$. Let us take an element $5$ from $V$ and choose $a=10$. $ax$, in this case, will be $50$ which is not included in either $V$ or $W$.

Comment: “... that set” refers to “The (set of the) vector space generated by the union...”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$V=[2,4,7,5]$$ and $$W=[5,8,2,1]$$ in your example are not vector spaces.

These are just vectors.

The vector space generated by those two linearly independent vectors is a two dimensional vector space which is made out of all possible linear combination of these two vectors.

If your scalar is $a=5$, then $ aV=5V = [10,20,35,25]$ is an element of your new vector space.

Comment: So the text should have said "so for any vector x in either V or W, ax is in the span( V U W ) rather than "so for any vector x in either V or W, ax is in that set" ?